# Bash subtraction malfunction: var=$((var-1)) gives ridiculous values

Tags: linux, bash, loops, math, while-loop

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$1;
while [[ "$var" -ge "0" ]];
do
  echo -ne "$var"\\r;
  var=$((var-1));
  sleep 1;
done
```

It works fine unless I pass the argument `10` (that is var=10), in that case the countdown shows: `10, 90, 89, 88,...` I also tried `var=$[var-1];` and even tried to store the variable in a temporary file and and reading it from there while updating it in the loop, same strange behavior! Why is it not working?

Linux version: **Debian Wheezy**

Comment: Why not write it simply as `((var--))`?

Comment: ((var--)) doesn't solve it either, because bash is fine as @Szczad explained, it has to do with how I print the output using echo "      "\\r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bash freaking out. It's the way TTY prints your values. You are sending `\r` which is `carret return` code. This way you print the number and the carret is moved back to the beginning of the line. So indeed the `echo` prints `10`, `9`, `8`, .. but it does not erase the second char. Try patching your code like this:

```
echo -ne "$var   "\\r;
```

and look at the output. You could also change `\r` to `\n` and see what happens then.

Comment: Holy monster in a closet!!! I tried your solution, first with a "tab" that didn't work, but "space" worked! Thanks...